# Extract index of values in specified multiples

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector of distances (meters):

```
my.distance <- c(0, 61, 122, 182, 242, 302, 363, 424, 485, 548, 611, 673,
                 735, 859, 920, 982, 1044, 1105, 1166, 1227, 1288, 1348,
                 1410, 1471, 1532, 1593, 1655, 1716, 1778, 1839, 1901, 1963, 
                 2025)
```

I want to pull out the index numbers of those distances that are in multiples of 500 into another vector, say `my.500s`. If there is no distance that is exactly in multiples of 500, then the next largest value will be taken:

```
print(my.500s)
[1] 10  17  25  33
```

I managed to do it in a bit of a hacky way:

```
my.distance.500round <- floor(my.distance/500)           #round distances to 500 m
diff.distance <- cumsum(table(my.distance.500round))     #how many of each is there
diff.distance.minus <- table(my.distance.500round)-1     #the above minus 1
my.500 <- as.numeric(diff.distance-diff.distance.minus)  #subtract the 
                                                         #difference to get 
                                                         #the index numbers
print(my.500)                                            #Tadaaaaaaa!
my.distances[my.500]                                     #The end goal
```

This is a bit long-winded, and I have done things in R where other people have shown me techniques that are much faster, eg. only using one line of code. I was wondering if this had a much shorter, more elegant, ***R*** way of accomplishing the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do something different with the euclidean division.

```
my.distance%/%500
my.distance%%500
my.500 <- data.table(my.distance%/%500,my.distance%%500,my.distance,c(1:length(my.distance)))

my.500 <- my.500 %>% group_by(V1) %>% slice(which.min(V2))
```

**#Distances**

```
my.500$my.distance
[1]    0  548 1044 1532 2025
```

**#Indexes**

```
my.500$V4
[1]  1 10 17 25 33
```

I explain it now. First line, we calculate the quotient of the division. Then, we take the remainder of the division. I created a data.table to make it more beautiful. Then we just need to keep the lines with the lowest remainder group by the quotient. So you can use `dplyr` `group_by` to make it beautiful.

I hope it's ok for you.

Comment: This is certainly more succinct than mine, and it does work for my larger data set

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
# For indexes 
> which(diff(floor(c(0, my.distance)/500))==1)
#[1] 10 17 25 33

#For values
my.distance[which(diff(floor(c(0, my.distance)/500))==1)]
#[1]  548 1044 1532 2025
```

Comment: nice succint solution

Answer (score 0):

If you need the number 1593 to be selected as well, you could try:

```
> which(c(floor(my.distance/100)) %% 5 == 0 & my.distance > 500)
[1] 10 17 25 26 33
> my.distance[which(c(floor(my.distance/100)) %% 5 == 0 & my.distance > 500)]
[1]  548 1044 1532 1593 2025
```